# Équivalent de "We couldn't catch a cold" ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, locutions

Je demande commend rendre la locution anglaise [*couldn't catch a cold*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/couldn%27t+catch+a+cold).

> slang A jeer directed at an athlete who struggles with catching the
> ball. It is a pun in which the phrase "catch a cold" refers to
> becoming ill with the common cold (something that happens
> involuntarily). That bum in the outfield couldn't catch a cold—it's
> only the first inning, and he's already dropped two pop-ups!

Voici un context particulier (taken from the [Uriah Heep story](http://www.uriah-heep.com/newa/heepstory6.php)) :

> (...) Mick remembers a major incident in Philadelphia. "We were
> playing this 20, 000 seater and David, having been drinking heavily,
> rushes out onto the stage, steps onto one of the legs of the
> mike-stand and of course, it smacks him in the mouth.
> **The whole crowd roared, oblivious to what had happened but David,
> thinking they're having a go at him, turns round and says, 'You can go
> and fuck off if you don't like it.' I'm standing there at the side of
> the stage thinking 'Oh, no, he's just told 20,000 of our fans to fuck
> off!' We couldn't catch a cold there after that."** Hensley was so
> disgusted with the way Byron was going that he flew back to England
> and it was only Bron, who'd been in the middle of a holiday in
> Barbados, who managed to persuade him not to leave there and then.

Comment: Dans le cadre du Tennis, j'ai souvent entendu "*Il a un trou dans sa raquette*" (ou plutôt quelque chose comme "*Bah alors, t'as un trou dans ta raquette ?*")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans le contexte particulier des sports de ballons, l'expression *couldn't catch a cold* est plutôt adaptée à des sports typiquement américains comme le football US ou le baseball. Néanmoins, si l'on transpose la situation aux sports de ballons plus courants en France, on peut trouver des expressions plus ou moins équivalentes en football ("soccer"):

> C'est une passoire

se dit d'un gardien de but qui prend beaucoup de buts. On peut aussi étendre l'expression à toute une défense ou une équipe:

> La défense de cette équipe est une véritable passoire.

>

> Il s'est troué

se dit d'une action où un défenseur ou un gardien a complètement raté son action et est passé à côté du ballon.

On peut aussi penser à une expression tirée du billard, mais aujourd'hui utilisée pour n'importe quel domaine de compétence, même en dehors du sport: *ne pas en toucher une*

> J'ai besoin d'aide, je n'en touche pas une en informatique.

Dans les métaphores tirées du billard, on trouve aussi *toucher une/sa bille* qui signifie "être doué", et sa forme négative qui a alors le même sens que *ne pas en toucher une*.
Dans le même ordre d'idées, il y a aussi *toucher une/sa canette* et le négatif *ne pas toucher une/sa canette* (je ne trouve pas d'étymologie claire à ce sujet, mais j'imagine qu'il s'agit alors d'une *canette* de bière ou d'une autre boisson, utilisée comme balle pour jouer au football dans la rue).

> Il est gentil, mais il ne touche pas sa bille/sa canette en informatique.

Dans le contexte particulier de l'exemple du concert de rock, il serait assez incongru de reprendre la métaphore de la passoire ou des trous... Si je comprends bien l'idée générale, le groupe de rock a eu du mal à reconquérir son public après un incident sur scène. On pourrait alors dire:

> On a ramé après ça
>
> On a sorti les rames
>
> On en a bavé
>
> C'était foutu
>
> C'était mort (*rem: c'est une expression assez récente, très à la mode chez les ados qui signfie "c'est foutu", "pas la peine d'essayer"*)

Ou plus vulgairement, pour exprimer l'idée que tout effort fait envers une personne est inutile:

> Autant pisser dans un violon

Comment: Avec *ne pas en toucher* il y a aussi *il ne touche pas une bille* et *il ne touche pas une canette*.

Comment: Ce ne serait pas plutôt *toucher sa bille* pour dire "il est très doué", et de là, *il ne touche pas sa bille* pour dire "il est nul" ? J'avoue ne pas connaître la variante avec *canette*, c'est dans le sens de "canette de bière" ?

Comment: Il y a surement des variations régionales.  https://twitter.com/PierreMenes/status/886162940889624577 https://twitter.com/sebtpanam/status/955965574718337024

Comment: On a aussi « Il ne touche pas sa canette. » (régional)

Answer (score 1):

En français ce jeu de mot pourrait être traduit en :

> Il est tellement mauvais, qu'il ne pourrait même pas attraper un rhume.

En référence au fait qu'il n'arrive pas à attraper de balles.